# Apache beam global counter

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a file with say million records, and some of the records are bad records (which will be known when the records are processed in a ParDo).  I want to write the bad records to a separate PCollection along with their line numbers in which they appear in the file and good records to a separate PCollection.

Is there a way to maintain a global counter of the lines read so far across worker process so that I could use it to write out the line numbers?

Comment: You can use [metrics](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.5.0/apache_beam.metrics.metric.html) to keep track of the number of elements processed but that will not necessarily match the row in the input file as work is parallelized. Would it be possible to pre-process the data to include row numbers? For example, Dataprep with [SOURCEROWNUMBER](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/SOURCEROWNUMBER-Function_57344758).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Beam metrics to keep a global monitoring counter that you can query from your machine, or in the UI of your runner.

If you want to keep a precise collection of all of the bad records, along with information about them (e.g. line numbers), then you'd need to add a transform that lets you do that. Something like this:

```
original_records = p | LoadRecords()

class SplitRecords(beam.DoFn):
  BAD_RECORD_TAG = 'BadRecord'

  def process(self, record):
    if self.is_bad(record):
      # Output the record onto the 'special' BadRecord input.
      yield beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.BAD_RECORD_TAG, record)
    else:
      yield record   # Output the record onto the main input

record_collections = (original_records | 
                      beam.ParDo(SplitRecords()).with_outputs(
                          SplitRecords.BAD_RECORD_TAG,
                          main='GoodRecords'))

bad_records = record_collections[SplitRecords.BAD_RECORD_TAG]

good_records = record_collections['GoodRecords']
```

For a more detailed example, I'd recommend you look at the Apache Beam cookbook directory, which contains an [example with a multiple-output ParDo](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/multiple_output_pardo.py)

Comment: Hi @Pablo, I am using side outputs to generate the good and bad record pCollections.  However, using Metrics I could increment the counter whenever I process an element.  However, is there a way to query Metrics within a Pardo to get the current count? I believe one could query the metrics only after the job is completed.

Comment: You are not able to query metrics from within a ParDo (although you are able to query them from your program while the pipeline runs e.g. `p.metrics().query(...)`). To have a global counter that is accessible like that, you'd need something like a redis instance or memcached that you access within the ParDo. I believe once the State API is supported, you'll be able to do that as well